# Node js Winston multiple logs

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

guys, I'm working with [Winston logger](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston)

```
const twilioLogger = new winston.Logger({
     transports: [
        new winston.transports.File({
            level: 'info',
            filename: path,
            handleExceptions: true,
            json: false,
            maxsize: 5242880, // 5MB
            maxFiles: 1,
            colorize: false,
            formatter,
        }),
      ],
       exitOnError: false,
    });
```

Here above is my code sample, 
But I would like to create multiple loggers
for example, I have multiple Users, and each user should have his log created when the user is created, how can I do that with Winston,
as I see they are creating just one place to write logs???

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Winston. But as it is just a javascript object I am sure you can assign it as method of User instance.
For example, if you have something like this:

`let userOne = new User()`

You can assign a new method to this with

```
userOne.logger = new winston.Logger({
         transports: [
            new winston.transports.File({
                level: 'info',
                filename: path,
                handleExceptions: true,
                json: false,
                maxsize: 5242880, // 5MB
                maxFiles: 1,
                colorize: false,
                formatter,
            }),
          ],
           exitOnError: false,
        });
```

Comment: thanx I will try it :)

Comment: @legolas What is the result of your tryings?